# Web Extension intercept web request to contact native messaging to set a value of request cookie

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, callback, promise, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to intercept web request to a particular url and before sending the request, contact a native app through web extension native messaging (which is async). Since the native messaging is async, the web request gets sent before the cookie value is got from native messaging response.

Here is the code snippet. How to make this flow synchronous so that the cookie is loaded and then the intercepted web request is sent.

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
   loadCookie,
   {urls: ["https://some-url/*"]},
   ["blocking"]
);

function loadCookie(requestDetails)
{
    console.log("Gettting Cookie Data for"+requestDetails.url);
    var sending = browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage("native_app","getCookieData");
    sending.then(onSuccess, onError);
}

function onSuccess(response)
{
    console.log("Received: " + JSON.stringify(response));
    setCookie(response);
}

function onError(error)
{
    console.log("Error");
}

function setCookie(resp)
{
   if(typeof resp != 'undefined'){
   var now = new Date();
   var time = Math.round(now.getTime() / 1000);
   var expireTime = time + 15*60;
   browser.cookies.set({
    url: "https://some-domain/*",
    name: "req_cookie",
    value: resp,
    secure: true,
    expirationDate: expireTime
   });
   }
   console.log("Set a cookie");
}
```

Comment: I think your only chance is when the URL you want to intercept is a link on the page - you can initiate prefetching of the data in `mouseover` event listener so that it'll be ready before the link is clicked.

Comment: I can do that for hyperlinks but I need to do it for normal request that happen through user entering url in address bar.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the cookie header, I think you will need to listen to [onBeforeSendHeaders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeSendHeaders), not [onBeforeRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest).

The documentation for `onBeforeSendHeaders` (and `onBeforeRequest`) says :

> From Firefox 52 onwards, instead of returning a [BlockingResponse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/BlockingResponse), the listener can return a Promise which is resolved with a BlockingResponse. This enables the listener to process the request asynchronously.

Comment: Even if I use onBeforeSendHeaders, native messaging call and listener function is still async. I need to return the listener only after I receive the cookie value. Something like wait for promise to resolve/reject and then return.

Comment: No, read the quote above. Providing you are in FF 52+, you can **return a promise** from the listener. A BlockingResponse with which the promise is eventually resolved will be delivered in the same way as a BlockingResponse that is returned directly.